# ideals in Linfty algebras

Tags: homotopy-theory

Where is anything written about ideals in $L_\infty$ algebras?
What is the best formulation either in terms of coderivation formalism or 
explicit multivariable formulas. Does the `obvious' theorem about quotients by an ideal then follow?

Comment: Any problems logging in to your old account (http://mathoverflow.net/users/16682/jim-stasheff)?

Comment: Isn't there a natural notion of ideal for algebras over an arbitrary operad?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but can you give a reference?